# BlackBerry barcode scanning library?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, barcode-scanner

Anyone got a good handle on a barcode scanning library that can be used to read in UPC-A, EAN-13 or other major barcode formats based on input from the digital camera? Does RIM have a standard library already available for this?

I know that BlackBerry Messenger has 2D barcode scanning built-in so I'm guessing there must be something available, though not sure if it's proprietary or not.

---

**Update:** I'll go with the zxing library for now and see how that pans out since there aren't any official RIM libraries yet. I'll keep digging and update this question if I find anything else that's better in the meantime.

Comment: Haven't seen anything else yet. Anyone know of any other good barcode libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/#svn/trunk) lib, there are samples for BB.
Other are [huayu_sdk](http://code.google.com/p/huayusdk/) and [jjil](http://code.google.com/p/jjil/).

Comment: +1 - Hey thanks! I'll check out zxing and the others. Hopefully I'll be able to use them with OS 5+ etc.

Comment: Has anyone been able to get the BB examples to run? I'm using 5.0 (also tried 4.7), but it keeps crashing in the sim.

Answer (score 1):

RIM has not exposed any public APIs to assist with barcode scanning, even in the latest 5.0 APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's really crappy!! Wouldn't RIM want to keep pace with Android and iPhone?

Comment: Sometimes it takes a while for internal APIs used by RIM to trickle down to the public API.  They do listen to developers though so make sure to send them an email or post to the developer forums.

Comment: I'll do that. I've got some contacts that work for RIM as well so maybe I can do a little networking and see what's going on as well. Or at least get a litmus test for it.

Comment: [BlackBerry 6 now has a BarCode/QR API](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/10/barcode-api/)