# Is it possible to turn a blackberry camera to a barcode reader?

Tags: blackberry, barcode-scanner

I've got a blackberry curve, and it runs OS 5.
What APIs should I be looking at to use the camera as a barcode reader?

Comment: This won't help you right now, but OS 6 will have a builtin Barcode API: http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/07/blackberry-6-developers/

Comment: See also similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495049/blackberry-barcode-scanning-library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/).
It has a J2ME implementation so it should fit just fine.

EDIT: Also has a RIM specific section

Comment: This is really useful, will keep exploring it. Thanks

Comment: I've used the WinMobile version and I can vouch.