# Barcode scanner SDK for Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde, barcode-scanner

can anyone guide me to any of the efficient Barcode scanner SDK which can work in Blackberry SDK. while googling i have got to here about ZXing lib. But i failed to find the samples and to download the SDK.

Help me with some link to the SDK download and test code sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In past i faced the same problem,after googled i found ZXing bar code scanner api with sample.
The below link will really help you.

http://aliirawan-wen.blogspot.com/2011/05/barcode-scanner-for-blackberry-os-50.html

Answer (score 1):

Check this may be useful for u ...

[BlackBerry barcode scanning library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495049/blackberry-barcode-scanning-library)

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Barcode-reader-SDK-or-library/td-p/238641